# Unable to edit transaction names on the Blaze-meter recorder on particular sites

Tags: performance-testing, blazemeter, jmeter-5.0

I am unable to edit the transaction names using the blazemeter plugin recorder on our client site whereas I am able to do so in other sites.

I have tried it on multiple similar sites (our client application is an eCommerce application); it works on other sites but for some reason it doesn't work on our site.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should contact [BlazeMeter Support](https://blazemeter.com/support/) instead of asking questions on public forums, the support team members should have deeper knowledge regarding their product than anyone here.

As a workaround you can simply locate the relevant [Transaction Controllers](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller/) in the generated script and amend labels according to your business logic.